# как брать данные из другой активности sharepreferens

Tags: android

Здравствуйте, я начинающий разработчик и я создаю игру,  и мне надо что бы при проигрыше сохранялись данные, а потом эти данные выводить в другую активность смотря от того какая кнопка была нажата(какой был выбран уровень сложности)
Вот мой код сохранение данных:

```
shar=getSharedPreferences("sohr",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
edit=shar.edit();
```

Метод при проигрыше:

```
void game_over(){
            vz_texta();
            final AlertDialog.Builder adb= new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            adb.setTitle("Вы проиграли");
            adb.setMessage("Вы за игру набрали:"+v+ "\n"+"Начать сначал?");
            adb.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            adb.setCancelable(false);

            DialogInterface.OnClickListener negativeListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface p1, int p2)
                {

                    edit.putInt("sohr",v);
                    edit.commit();
                    finish();
                }
            };
            DialogInterface.OnClickListener positiveListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface p1, int p2)
                {
                    mainTextView1.setText("");
                    soz_primer();
                    s=60;
                    time.setText(""+s);
                    rez.setText(""+0);
                    adb.create();
                }
            };
            adb.setNegativeButton("Нет",negativeListener);
            adb.setPositiveButton("Да",positiveListener);
            AlertDialog alert = adb.create();
            alert.show();

        }
```

Но я не знаю как потом в другую активность передать мою константу и не знаю как можно сделать что бы данные сохранялись в зависимости от выбора сложности
Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: в другой активити создавайте новый экземпляр преференсов с тем же именем и читайте из него по ключам, в которые сохраняли в первой активити. Название ключа и имя преференсов лучше придумать разные и более "говорящие" о назначении.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получить значение в другой активности можно будет так:

```
SharedPreferences shar = getSharedPreferences("sohr", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
//0 - значение, которое вернётся, если по ключу не будет найдено число.
int a = shar.getInt("sohr", 0);
```

Главное, передать в метод getSharedPreferences то же имя файла, в какой вы записывали данные, и не напутать в ключах.